# Javascript: export * from ... make the build file too heavy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I got a bad performance after the build react-app.

I build my project with create-react-app.

My structure is:

```
/store
  actions.ts
  reducers.ts
  /module1
    module1.actions.ts
    module1.reducers.ts
  /moduleN
    moduleN.actions.ts
    moduleN.reducers.ts
  ...
```

In the /store/actions.ts I import and export all child action files `export * from module1/module1.actions.ts`

Then I can import and use actions in the reducers or components `import * as actions from store/actions.ts`

I am using library `redux-actions` to create and handle the actions.

But I got a problem with the actions.ts, it too heavy after build. You can take a look at a building analysis.

Is there any way I can reduce the size of the bundles?

Thank you!

[image: build analysis]

Comment: Is this a dev build?

Comment: this is a production build without gzip

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that I used the `createAction` function from the `redux-action` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-actions) which made the task files super heavy.

I removed and wrote the other `createAction` function